# Use location services not as fast as google-map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, gps, location-services

I would like to discuss with everyone, sharing why using location services is not as fast as google-map.

Now, I created two thread location-services:

- GoogleApiClient (With LocationServices.API)
- Custom own location services with GPS & Network provider

With GoogleAPIClient (LocationServices) I config

- PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
- FAST_INTERVAL_FUSED_POSITION (10 sec)
- INTERVAL_FUSED_POSITION (60 sec)

With own thread receive location from gps, network with 3 minutes I request get location from gps, network providers.

But sometime My app receive not fast as GoogleMap app. Ex:

- When a long time my app can't receive location, open Google Map takes
  location right away and re-open My App is ok.
- I always noticed google-map gets position in few seconds, and my app
  not fast as.

Everyone, who are using location service together discuss, sharing something to improve the speed of locating position.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Play Services fused location provider and its getLastLocation() method.  Documentation is available at https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html.

If location is enabled on your device before your app opens and you use this method, you should get a location fairly quickly.

Comment: Is FusedLocaitonAPI a part of GoogleAPI-LocationService ? I'm using it:  
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mLocationClient, request, this);

Comment: The Play Services location API is preferred over the Google API LocationServices that you just described.  From the documentation page that I just mentioned: "The Google Play services location APIs are preferred over the Android framework location APIs (android.location) as a way of adding location awareness to your app. If you are currently using the Android framework location APIs, you are strongly encouraged to switch to the Google Play services location APIs as soon as possible."